# c++ postfix expression with decimals and multi digits

Tags: c++, string, parsing, decimal

I'm struggling with a postfix expression that takes decimals. I can't figure out how to convert string to decimals or double digits... program works with numbers 1-9.

How can I make it possible for decimals to be used?

The function must take a string as parameter. My function:

```
double evalPostfix(string& input)
{
    stack<double> s;
    int i = 0;
    char ch;
    double val;

    while (i < input.size())
    {

        ch = input[i];
        if (isdigit(ch))
        {
            //Converting and pushing digit into stack
            s.push(ch - '0');
        }



    return val;
}
```

Comment: How about using a `std::stringstream`?

Comment: char symbol;
 double number;
 istringstream iss(input);
 while (iss) {
  if (iss >> number) {

   ex.push(number);
  }
  else if (iss >> symbol)    something like that?

Comment: Its not \*that\* easy, but yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
#include <limits>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

double eval(double lhs, double rhs, char op)
{
    switch (op) {
    case '+': return lhs + rhs;
    case '-': return lhs - rhs;
    case '*': return lhs * rhs;
    case '/':
        if (rhs != 0)
            return lhs / rhs;
    }

    return std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
}

double evalPostfix(std::string const &input)
{
    std::stack<double> values;
    std::stack<char> ops;
    std::stringstream ss{ input };

    for(;;) {
        for (;;) {
            auto pos{ ss.tellg() };  // remember position to restore if
            double value;
            if (!(ss >> value)) {   // extraction fails.
                ss.clear();
                ss.seekg(pos);
                break;
            }
            values.push(value);
        }

        char op;
        if (!(ss >> std::skipws >> op))
            break;

        if (op != '+' && op != '-' && op != '*' && op != '/') {
            std::cerr << '\'' << op << "' is not a valid operator!\n\n";
            return std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
        }

        if (values.size() < 2) {
            std::cerr << "Not enough values!\n\n";
            return std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
        }

        double op2{ values.top() };
        values.pop();
        double op1{ values.top() };
        values.pop();
        values.push(eval(op1, op2, op));
    }

    if (values.size() > 1) { // if we got here and there is more than 1 value left ...
        std::cerr << "Not enough operators!\n\n";
        return std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
    }

    return values.top();
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter the postfix expression: ";
    std::string exp;
    std::getline(std::cin, exp);
    double result = evalPostfix(exp);
    std::cout << "==> evaluates to " << result << '\n';
}
```

Comment: that helps a lot. thank you. could you tell me what its doing here : for(;;) {
        std::streampos pos;
        for (;;) {
            pos = ss.tellg();
            if (!(ss >> value))
                break;
            values.push(value);
        }

        ss.clear();
        ss.seekg(pos);

        if (!(ss >> std::skipws >> op))
            break;

Comment: The inner for loop tries to extract `double`s from the stringstream until that fails. When extraction fails it sets the reading position back to where it was before the last (failed) extraction. `if (!(ss >> std::skipws >> op)) break;` tries to extract one character and breaks the outer `for`-loop if that fails.